# what is the difference between using function outside of the class to encapsulate instead of using module design pattern in JS?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, ecmascript-5

I am learning the different design patterns in JS and came accross the module design pattern. I understand the intent and how it works, however, coming from a background of OOP, I don't see a difference between module pattern and just simply having function in a file outside of the class.
In snapshot 1 - I have `privateFunctionClass` that is outside of the `ModulePatternClass` and it's not available to outside world because I am on exporting it and only using inside `ModulePatternClass`
In the snpashot 2 - I use the module approach which encapsulates `privateFunction`
In both situations I encapsulate the function not be accessible to the outside world. Are those 2 approached identical or I am missing and not seeing something here that differ these 2 approaches?
Thank you in advance

```
function privateFunctionClass(){
    return 'this is a private function'
}

class ModulePatternClass{
    publicFunctionClass(){
        return 'I am a public function';
    }
    canAccessPrivateFunction(){
        return privateFunctionClass();
    }

}

module.exports = ModulePatternClass;
```

```
const ModulePatternClass = require('./module-pattern-class')

let modulePattern = (function(){

    let publicFunction =  function(){
        return 'I am a public function';
    }

    function privateFunction(){
        return 'this is a private function'
    }
    return{
        publicFunction:publicFunction()
    }
})();

console.log(modulePattern.publicFunction);
console.log(modulePattern.privateFunction);

console.log(new ModulePatternClass().publicFunctionClass());
```

Comment: No, declaring a "module" is *NOT* the same as " just simply having function in a file outside of the class".  Look [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Modules) and [here](https://javascript.info/modules-intro).  Note, too, that there are different *KINDS* ("implementations") of "modules":, including [AMD](https://javascript.info/modules-intro), [CommonJS](http://wiki.commonjs.org/wiki/Modules/1.1) and [RequireJS](https://requirejs.org/)

Comment: The module pattern is relevant for scripts (that run in the global scope), not for (ES6/CommonJS/AMD/UMD) modules.

Comment: The major obvious difference is that the first pattern unnecessarily exports a `class` (that needs to be instantiated with `new`) while the second simply uses an object literal. You can use object literals with `module.exports` as well, or return a class from an IIFE, to get equivalent usage.